# Why did the Shankaracharya of Puri said Arya Samaj is based on philosophy of shri Ramanujacharya?

Tags: ramanujacharya, vishishtadvaita

Please find the statement below :
https://youtu.be/Gh67Ht0JjvQ

Does Arya Samaj follow the theology of Vishishtadvait principle by Shri ramanuja ?